# Replacing all letters and equal signs with a space

Tags: java, text, writer

I'm trying to remove all the letters from a text file that contains random numbers and letters using this code

```
package textEdit;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class RemoveLetters {



    public static void readFile(String file) {
        try {
            FileReader fis = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fis);
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
            BufferedWriter bwriter = new BufferedWriter(writer);
            String line = null;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < symbolsAndLetters.length; i++) {
                    String str = symbolsAndLetters[i];
                    str = str.replace(str, ""); 
                }
            }
            reader.close();
            bwriter.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   

    public static String[] symbolsAndLetters = {"A", "B", "C",
        "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", 
        "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y",
        "Z", "=","a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", 
        "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t",
        "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z",};

    /**
     * @param args
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        readFile("c:/users/Kyle/workspace/Learn more java/src/music.txt");
    }

}
```

The problem is, it removes everything from the file, I'm very new to reading and writing in Java, so can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What do you think this line - `str = str.replace(str, "");` does?

Comment: You aren't replacing the line, nor writing the changes to the a file.

Comment: also keep in mind ["In place replacing usually isn't possible for files"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147615/replace-string-in-file)

Comment: (but you can always load in memory and then replace like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032223/java-load-file-replace-string-save))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you're actually doing within your `while` loop (read the comments):

```
// iterating over the items of your own static array (without fast enumeration)
for (int i = 0; i < symbolsAndLetters.length; i++) {
    // initializing a new String and assigning it the value of your array
    // that is currently indexed in your for-loop
    String str = symbolsAndLetters[i];
    // replacing the String's content by replacing its value 
    // (1st parameter, the "str" value itself)
    // with an empty String
    str = str.replace(str, ""); 
}
```

This accomplishes strictly nothing.

Here's what you want to do.

- Assign your writer to a new file. You can always replace the original afterwards.
- Or better, just use a `StringBuilder` and replace the contents of the original with the 
  `toString` representation of the `StringBuilder` once the original reader is closed.
- Remove the useless "characters" `String` array
- Use regex as such:

  ```
  // your outer loop iterating over each line of your input file

  while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

      // writing a new String representing the line read from the
      // original,
      // but replacing each of its alphabetic characters (through regex)
      // with an empty String
      writer.write(line.replaceAll("\\p{Alpha}", ""));
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I would create a new file to write output to.  Here I just append the word "new" to it.
-- FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file + "new");

Then use regular expressions to replace the characters you want
-- line=line.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]", "");

Then append it to the new file:
-- bwriter.append(line +"\n");

Answer (score 0):

Inside of your `while` loop, after the `for` loop, you should be writing the line back to the file.

When the loop steps to the next line, it looses everything in `str`.

You already open the file output stream, but never write anything to it. It does not *overwrite everything*, it does not write anything.

Comment: It actually overwrites everything, basically creates a new empty file.

Comment: I've not tested it, but can you simultaneously write back to a file you are reading? Maybe I'm old school, but I'd be writing to temp file, once done, close both files, delete the original and rename the temp back into its place

Comment: If you read the link from the comment on the OP, you will see that what should be done is write to a temp file and move when finished.