# Can Scanner be used to write to a file?

Tags: java, android, java.util.scanner

I have the following code snippet

```
    /* I have got the file. Now moving to the desired place */
Scanner in_chap = new Scanner(chap);
in_chap.useDelimiter(qa_delimiter);
while (in_chap.hasNext()) {
    String str = get_my_info();
            /* Now I need to replace the the current line with str */
     }
```

Is there way to use the scanner reference to write str to the new offset?  If I cannot is there any other way to do it? I need to use scanner to get to that line. Now I want to replace that with new string...

Comment: No Scanner objects are for input only.

Comment: No. `Scanner` provides *read only* access.

Comment: @pst: (ahead by a fraction of a second!)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147615/replace-string-in-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, as the name says, it's a `Scanner`, it's only used for reading, not for writing.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there way to use the scanner reference to write str to the new offset?

No. `Scanner` class is for reading purpose only.