# How to change a value of a file using Java IO function

Tags: java, android, java-io

Can anyone help me how to change a line in a file using java IO function. The file is located at *SDCard*. I have tried some solution from different blog, but failed.

I need to change one attribute `wpa_oper_channel=1` to `2,3,4.....` as user demand in the file `sdcard/sample.txt`.

I have also tried using `SED` command, but still not working. Please suggest if there any solution using java IO function.

The Command I have used using `SED` :

```
sed -i 's/wpa_oper_channel=[0-9]\\+/wpa_oper_channel=7/' sample.txt
```

Comment: please don't just describe what you have tried. Post the code, instead, and why it didn't work

Comment: So what's the issue?

Comment: I have updated the questions, please get the issue. I want to change the value after `wpa_oper_channel=` using java IO function, as `sed` is not working for `Android`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147615/replace-string-in-file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147615/replace-string-in-file)

Comment: @NayeemMorshedTushar Is there any information regarding file format? It seems like a properties file. If its a properties file you can read it and then change the property and then save it again.

Comment: Actually It is a `configuration` file in the `root` system directory. the file format is `filename.conf` in the location `/data/misc/`. I can change the file format to `filename.txt` also and save it in SDcard location. @bhdrkn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your configuration file is in the form of a Properties file. This means each line is in a format of `key=value`. You can easily read, modify and write it. Here is an example, I assume you have no problem with reading and writing a file through streams.

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File file = new File(sdcard,"sample.txt");
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file); // Read your existing file
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(is);
props.setProperty("wpa_oper_channel", "4");
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file); // Your output file stream
prop.store(output, null); // Save your properties file without header
```

By doing this, you may lose if there is another type of line like comments or else.

### Update

I updated to source code. But still you need to get read and write permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I haven't test the code, It will work with some exception handling. If it is not work please specify your error.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Can you plz provide a working demo code? I think i am facing some consistency problem...

Comment: Wow... It works !!! But I have lost all other `key=value` properties like
`update_config=1`
`ap_scan=1`
`model_name=SAMSUNG_MOBILE` etc.
I need to change only `wpa_oper_channel=4` keeping rest unchanged.

Comment: @NayeemMorshedTushar Sorry i forget to add load statement.

Answer (score 0):

What android do you use?

From android 4.4+ user haven't access to edit and remove files from SD Card. You must copy them to external storage and use there. See this link - http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67570

Comment: My Android version is `jelly Bean 4.2.2`

Answer (score 0):

You just have to

- read the file's content into memory (there are [millions of examples](http://bfy.tw/HYk) on how to do that with java),
- change the content (finding the position could be done using e.g.  `indexOf("wpa_oper_channel=")`)
- write the content back to the file (there are [millions of examples](http://bfy.tw/HYm) for that too)